# Elasticsearch Histogram Aggregation - Offset Interval Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, histogram, aggregation

Elasticsearch has [a histogram aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html) that puts results in various buckets. The documentation indicates that you can control the interval size of the buckets, but how do you control the offset of the interval?

Put another way: in Elasticearch, the buckets are all based off of zero, so an interval of 5 would yield buckets `0 --> 4`, `5 --> 9`, `10 --> 14`, `...`. But I would like to control the initial offset of the buckets, to generate buckets centered around zero, such as: `-2 --> 2`, `3 --> 8`, `...`.

Is there any way to control the offset of the bucket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the data fed into histogram using script.
Here using the script , i am subtracting 2 from all the numbers used to created the buckets.

```
{
  "aggs" : {
      "histoWithOffset" : {
               "histogram" : {
                      "field" : "numberField",
                      "script" : "_value - 2"
                        }
              }
        }
}
```